# UITableViewCell Won't Highlight

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

For some reason, none of my `UITableViewCell`s are highlighting blue. In IB, I have it set to highlight blue, and I have no code that is overriding IB.

Do you notice anything that might be causing this?

[image]

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int showID = [[[singleton.programs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"id"]intValue];
    //creates the url and loads the list of products
    //NSLog(@"showID: %d", showID);
    URLCreator * productsURL = [[URLCreator alloc] initStandard:@"getProgramProductsForList"];
    [productsURL addParam:@"id" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", showID]];
    WebManager *productsWM = [[WebManager alloc]init];
    [productsWM load:[productsURL finalURL] withSelector:@selector(parseProducts) object:[NSNumber numberWithInt:showID]];
}
```

My custom cell has nothing in it at the moment besides the `@property/@synthesize@, but here it is.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Comment: Mind to post the relevant code for your custom cells and your table delegate cellForRow... function? Maybe in your custom cell you're not calling [super setSelected:] or something, dunno

Comment: Do you want the blue color to be highlighter when user select/touch any row.?

Comment: Yes. In essence, it should be feedback when they touch the row before it transitions.

Comment: Does your custom cell use a custom background image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your case is simple enough that the best way to solve it is probably making an minimal example which works properly (default table view cell with blue selection) and add to it step by step (or in binary search steps) until it breaks.

If the minimal code breaks after some addition then you pinpointed the problem. If it doesn't, and you have actually reached the same thing that you appear to be using in your project, compare and see where the difference is which you haven't noticed.

Comment: I have since removed the link from IB to the ViewController and I am still having the issue. I also removed all subviews AND started a new TableViewController (just for testing) in the same project and I have the same issue. It's very, very weird.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this...?

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a mistake I've made in the past. Is your UITableView in edit mode? If so, is selection during editing enabled?

By default it's not enabled. In Interface Builder, select the UITableView and find the 'Editing' property under 'Table View' in the Utilities pane. Make sure 'Single Selection During Editing' is selected.

Also check that 'Single Selection' is enabled in general.

Comment: It is not in editing mode. I enabled the "Single Selection During Editing" anyway (just in case) but still no dice. :/

Comment: Does `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` get called as expected when you select a row?

Comment: Yes. Everything works as expected (except for this darn highlight! lol)

Answer (score 1):

Might be a fleeting answer, but just to  cover the simple things, you made sure you assigned the table view cell to your custom UITableViewCell subclass?

[image: Custom Class assignment]

Comment: Yes. Even when I removed it just to test if the default highlighting would be there, it wasn't. I even started a new TableViewController with a button that segues directly from the home screen just to test. Still no-go. It's weird. The only time I can get selection to work is in an entirely new project.

Comment: Weird. if you haven't already, run a clean then rebuild. Also an alternative way to get the highlight is to call the `setHighlighted:animated:` method of the UITableViewCell class, stick that in the delegate method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

Did your cell subviews occupy the entire cell bounds, and totally opaque? if so, even already highlighted with blue, there is no effect will visible.

Comment: No, I removed all subviews. I even started a new TableViewController with a button that segues directly from the home screen just to test. Still no-go. It's weird. The only time I can get selection to work is in an entirely new project.

Answer (score 0):

> No, I removed all subviews. I even started a new TableViewController with a button that segues directly from the home screen just to test. Still no-go. It's weird. The only time I can get selection to work is in an entirely new project. – James yesterday

As you mention it only happens in this project and not when you start a new project have you tried cleaning the project in Xcode (Product>Clean) and deleting your app from the simulator? Run again. Solves lots of odd issues.

Answer (score 0):

You said that it doesn't happen in new projects, have you tried making a new storyboard fie in your project to see if that has any effect?

The .storyboard file is just an xml file and, perhaps, there's something bad in the xml file...wouldn't hurt to try.